# How to avoid breaking hyperlinks but nicely wrap them within the container?

Tags: html, css, angular

Today, while playing with new angular I faced problem as attached:

[image]

The "tags" are expanding throughout the parent container (the white div). They wrap, but badly, as you see.

I would like them to do not break in the middle of the word, but in this case the "software engineering" should be entirely in the second row.

The tags are encapsulated in div as follows:

```
<div class="menu-block">
  <div class="menu-header">
    <strong>&raquo; Tags</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-content tags">
    <tags></tags>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the appropriate CSS classes:

```
.menu-block {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    padding: 1.2em;
    border-left: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

.menu-block .menu-header {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    font-size: 14pt;
}

.menu-block .menu-content {
    font-size: 11pt;
    /* See the specifications below */
}

.menu-block .tags {
    font-size: 11pt;
    line-height: 2.2em;
}
```

The .menu-block element is also encapsulated in bootstrap .col-4.

And the last thing: angular  component (I think annotation is enough here):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tags',
    template: `
    <a *ngFor="let tagFeed of tagFeeds" class="tag" href="/tag/{{tagFeed.id}}">{{tagFeed.id}}</a>
    `,
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change in css

```
.tag {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

online demo http://codepen.io/tieppt/pen/WRyMVZ

Comment: Works! :) Thank you